# PhpSpreadsheet: How to check if a cell has a strikethrough?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, strikethrough

How to check in PhpSpreadsheet if a cell has a strikethrough ?

Tried this one:

```
    $cell0 = $sheet->getCell('C73');
    $isStriked = $cell0->getStyle()->getFont->getStrikethrough();
    print_r($isStriked);
```

doesn't work whether the target cell has a strikethrough or not it gives a blank value...

Comment: Try: `$isStriked = $cell0->getFont->getStrikethrough();`

Comment: Just found out that PhpSpreadsheet does not support strikethrough for XLSX files. https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/features-cross-reference/

Comment: @Luuk you need to have getStyle before using getFont.

Comment: I just hoped it was like in VBA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.font.strikethrough `ActiveCell.Font.Strikethrough = True`.

Comment: `getFont` is not a property, it's a method and it needs to be followed by `()`.

Answer (score 1):

For Strikethrough you need a font object see documentation here [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#Valid_array_keys_for_style). To check you must use `getStrikethrough()`. To set you must use `setStrikethrough()`. See documentation [here](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Style-Font.html#method_getStrikethrough)

```
$cell0 = $sheet->getCell('C73');
$isStriked = $cell0->getStyle()->getFont()->getStrikethrough();
```